# Is there an existing script to automate compiling email address from the "sent" folder of Outlook and OWA into a CSV file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, script, csv, outlook-web-access

I'm an employee of a small business and we pay for a task service to manually comb through the "sent" folder of our email accounts and create a list of email addresses we have sent emails to.  Though this isn't a huge expenditure, I feel that there may be a better and free way to do this with a script.  Essentially, we want to compile those email addresses into a CSV file which can then be uploaded to the web-based service we use for our newsletters and calendar/events, either weekly or daily.  Luckily, the web service that we use to distribute this content will automatically de-dupe the email addresses, so that's not an issue that necessarily needs to be addressed.  I understand the world of scripting can help automate some processes, and I'm wondering if this particular task could be automated to suit this purpose.  Any thoughts, comments, pointers, or advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need any scripts for that. Just use the Export to CSV function built-in to Outlook: File -> Import/Export -> Export to a file -> Comma Separated Values -> Sent Items -> CSV file name -> Map Fields as Needed.